# Query inserting 'Array' instead of value into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Trying to set up a scheduler with a checkbox, when I check multiple time slots I would like the checked times to each be inserted into my table.

I have timeslots set up in my database as an enum, so this just displays all the times in checkbox form.

```html
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";    
  echo("<td><input type=checkbox name=time_slot[] value='$option'>$option</td>");
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

This code is supposed to insert each checked item into the database with all the same information bar the timeslot.

```html
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $ts = $_POST['time_slot'];
  $db = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=zzzzz", "zzzzz", "12345");
  for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($ts);$i++)
  {
    $query = "INSERT INTO timeslot (date, duration, firstName, lastName) VALUES ('".$_POST['year']."-".$_POST['month']."-".$_POST['day']."', '$ts', '".$_SESSION['firstName']."', '".$_SESSION['lastName']."')";
 $state = $db->prepare($query);
 $state->execute();
 print_r($state);
  }
 print_r($ts);
```

Each loop for the `print_r($state)` outputs `INSERT INTO timeslot (date, duration, firstName, lastName) VALUES ('2020-04-20', 'Array','John', 'Doe')`.

The `print_r($ts)` outputs all the timeslots that i've checked `Array ( [0] => 4:20-4:40 PM [1] => 4:40-5:00 PM [2] => 5:00-5:20 PM )`

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Use it like  `$ts[$i]`

Answer (score 2):

If you're looping through $ts, you might want to use the $i to grab the value at that index on each loop. `'" . $ts[$i] . "'`

```
$query = "INSERT INTO timeslot (date, duration, firstName, lastName) VALUES ('".$_POST['year']."-".$_POST['month']."-".$_POST['day']."', '" . $ts[$i] . "', '".$_SESSION['firstName']."', '".$_SESSION['lastName']."')";
```

Comment: Can't believe i overlooked something that simple, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use time-slot as below to get comma separated value of it:

```
$ts = implode(",",$_POST['time_slot']);
```